# GitVersion and custom version

Tags: azure-devops, gitversion

My organization has a git repository that has been in use for years. We have our own tagging system. When a release branch is cut for production release at the end of a sprint, we create a tag vSprint-< SprintNumber >-< year >
We are now containerizing the application and using GitVersion we want to come up with an automated strategy to determine the tag. The issue is that when GitVersion tries to calculate the SemVer, it is picking the highest < SprintNumber> (but the tag is from a release branch from a previous year) as the Major version. Is there a way to enforce the major version as '1'?
I tried using 'next-version' property in gitversion.yaml but it works only if the version is greater than what gitversion calculates.